# ReactJS Uncaught TypeError: this.refs issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use `refs` to access a `DOM node` in React, however, I am getting the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.refs.card.getDomNode is not a function(…)

I am [following this tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-using-tweenmax-with-react), and as far as I can tell this should work.

Here is the code I have written. Can anyone spot anything obvious i am doing wrong.

```
var App = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function() {
        var card = this.refs.card.getDomNode();
    },

    render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Card ref="card"/>              
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: `.getDomNode();` depricated

Answer (score 1):

From **0.15** onwards React depricated `.getDOMNode()`

> this.getDOMNode() is now deprecated and ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this) can
>   be used instead.

Use like this

```
componentDidMount: function() {
   var card = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.card);
},
```

For more details see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to the following [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5074)

You need to change the following

```
function() {
        var card = this.refs.card.getDomNode();
    },
```

**TO THIS**

```
function() {
              var card = this.refs.card;
    },
```

*If it points to the `input,select,div` DOM node*

and

```
function() {
                var mmo =  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.card);
        },
```

*for the `custom component` you have created yourself*